# Can't understand how to invoke my own theme() function

Tags: theming

i have made formexample.module, from **Drupal 7 Pro Development**

```
function formexample_menu() {
    $items['formexample'] = array(
        'title' => 'View the sample form',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('formexample_nameform'),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );
    return $items;
}

function formexample_nameform() {
    $form['name'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Your name'),
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#description' => t('what people call you'),
    );

    $form['name']['user_name'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Your name'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#description' => t('please enter name'),
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    return $form;
}
```

and a theme function and preprocess function

```
function formexample_theme() {
    return array(
        'formexmaple_nameform' => array(
            'render element' => 'form',
            'template' => 'formexample-nameform',
        ),
    );
}

function template_preprocess_formexample_nameform(&$variables) {
    $variables['name'] = $variables['form']['name'];
    $variables['submit'] = $variables['form']['submit'];
}
```

this is template file for this theme() - **formexample-nameform.tpl.php**

```
<div id="formexample_nameform">
<?php
    print render($name);
    print render($submit);
?>
</div>
```

**my question is:** how and where to invoke this `theme('formexample_nameform')` , i thought i should insert `function template_preprocess_formexample_nameform` to my template.php file(with **template** rename to my theme name) but its not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set it on the `$form` element inside your form function:

```
function formexample_nameform($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#theme'] = 'formexmaple_nameform';
  // ...
```

When you use `render element` with a theme the variable on which you set `#theme` is the one that's passed through to the theme/preprocess functions.

Don't forget to add [`drupal_render_children()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_render_children/7) at the bottom of your template file or the form won't render correctly:

```
echo drupal_render_children($form);
```